# What is the best ration to divide my image dataset into train/validation for Mask_RCNN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, dataset

I have 13k images , i want to choose the best ratio to divide
my dataset into train/validation to use this model 
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
for object detection and instance segmentation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: There are many sites on line to give you guidance on how to divide your data set for particular tasks.  An off-site link is heavily discouraged on Stack Overflow.  The basic answer for a specific model that you have to experiment to see what works.  If you want more guidance than that, you'll need to post the analysis results of your research and a more specific question.

Comment: There is no best train/test split ratio, just choose one and stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the common ratios are: `60/20/20 %(train/val/test)`. 
Hope that helps.